# MySql merge rows and show item count in result table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to get the result as shown in this figure from the table:
[image]

How can i do this using mysql query?
Thank you,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT `UID`, `USER`, COUNT(RID) AS "RID-Count", SUM(`COUNT`) AS COUNT
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY `UID`, `USER`
```

Assuming for `cat` the RID is `NULL`